# How to draw my own tooltip without shadow?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am trying to draw my own tooltip. But I cant get rid of the standard shadow.

Its a standard WinForm application, with lots of forms. So therefore is

```
 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

called, and needed, when the application starts. If I comment out this line, it works. I made a minimal WinForm app below. If EnableVisualStyles is commented out, it draws a red rectangle only. When I uncomment it, it draws a red rectangle with a shadow.

Does anyone know ho to solve this? How to have Application.EnableVisualStyles(), and have a tooltip 100% OwnerDrawn, without any standard shadows?

[image]

[image]

Minimal WinForm app is here:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ToolTipExample
{
  public class MainForm : Form
  {
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
          // Comment out below line and it works.
          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.Run(new MainForm());
      }

      private ToolTip toolTip;
      private Button button;

      public MainForm()
      {
          toolTip = new ToolTip();
          toolTip.OwnerDraw = true;
          toolTip.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(toolTip1_Draw);
          toolTip.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(toolTip1_Popup);

          button = new Button();
          button.Location = new Point(25, 25);
          button.Text = "Button";

          toolTip.SetToolTip(button, "Button tip text");

          Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { button });
      }

      private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
      {
          e.ToolTipSize = new Size(100, 100);
      }

      private void toolTip1_Draw(System.Object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
      {
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.Bounds);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: [not straightforward](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolTip.cs,2389). a draft, derived from the implementation: a) obtain the hWnd to the internal ("TT_...") tooltip host window b) call `GetClassLongPtr32` about `GCL_STYLE` if it has the `CS_DROPSHADOW` style, if yes then c) call `SetClassLongPtr32` about `GCL_STYLE`, with the original style minus the CS_DROPSHADOW flag bit.

Comment: related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/728fe9ae-d32a-4b0a-96a8-fd5ce36b3ef0/how-to-disable-shadow-for-particultar-control?forum=winforms and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43061307/1132334

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Thanks for the links also. I never got these in the results when I did a search on Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the class style of the `ToolTip` using `GetClassLong` and then remove `CS_DROPSHADOW` style from it and set the class style for the `ToolTip` again:

```
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public const int GCL_STYLE = -26;
public const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x20000;

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClassLong")]
public static extern int GetClassLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetClassLong")]
public static extern int SetClassLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e) 
{
    e.ToolTipSize = new Size(100, 100);
    var hwnd = (IntPtr)typeof(ToolTip).GetProperty("Handle",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(toolTip);
    var cs = GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_STYLE);
    if ((cs & CS_DROPSHADOW) == CS_DROPSHADOW)
    {
        cs = cs & ~CS_DROPSHADOW;
        SetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_STYLE, cs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked right away with the above code! I wish Microsoft sometimes did an major update on .Net WinForms controls and solve all details like this.

Comment: Hmmm, I wish they had such plan. Anyway, you're welcome :)

Comment: This worked a treat with a custom tooltip control, where I needed to position bottom right corner or the form and the shadow was awful, this took care of the job! Thank you :)